# Writing a unit test in gtest for a function returning an nlohmann::json object

Tags: c++, json, unit-testing, googletest

This is my function that I would like to create a test for:

```c++
static nlohmann::json parse_json(const std::string& file_path)
{
    std::ifstream i(file_path);
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(i);
    return j;
}
```

I understand this type of test:

```cpp
TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesZeroInput) {
  EXPECT_EQ(Factorial(0), 1);
}
```

But when my function is returning an object I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this. Is this where mocking comes into play?
Where I would need to write something like this:

```cpp
class fakeJsonObject {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD(nlohmann::json, parse_json, std::string& file_path);
};
```

Then create a test with my mocked object and compare it to an object created from my `parse_json` function?

Comment: `Factorial(0)` returns an object as well. You can apply the same pattern `EXPECT_EQ( call_some_function( ...params...), expected_result)`

Comment: `0` and `1` are also objects (by definition of the C++ object model), why should an object representing JSON be different?

Comment: Just a note that using a `std::ifstream` is a good sign that you're not making a __unit__ test here.  A good unit test is _fast_ and does not depend on external state (such as filesystem).  You probably want to be testing the `nlohmann::json::parse()` function (you can pass a `std::istringstream` for a fast, repeatable, self-contained test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General answer : a good unit test follow the rule AAA

Arrange :  place where you prepare things that will be tested

Act : function call under test

Assert : Assert that the function call gives you the right result.

So in your case you have to prepare / or better generate a file containing json data. (Arrange).

Call the function. (Act)

Assert you got a nlhohmann::json object which is related to the json data contained in the file.(Assert)